# How to add a new shape on top by default

Tags: konvajs

I'm working on a KonvaJS application and it's like a Paint application including drawing functionality. But when I'm using the pencil tool I want to have the new shape on top.

When I'm adding a new shape to my layer, it always gets a `index=0` by default:

```
layer.add(newShape);
stage.add(layer);
layer.draw();
```

Is there any way to add a new shape on top by default? Something like `moveToTop()` function does.

Comment: What index do you expect to have if you have just one shape inside?

Comment: My issue is with more than one shape. If a currently have shape `A` with index = 0, then if I add a new shape `B`, I want: `A`: 0, `B`: 1. The current behavior moves shape `A` to 1, and put `B` on 0. Makes sense?

Comment: This is my issue. I want the new blue line on top:
[video example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LfKZTQ1tP15-qxnmIZyislWgBmF8xtbr)

Comment: This looks like a bug in your code but there is not yet a large enough code sample to confirm. Can you edit your question and paste a for-next loop with 2 passes through the loop and put code within the loop to add a shape on each pass, offsetting the shape position slightly? Ensure it works before you post it in your question.

Comment: Shape `A` will not change the index in that case. Please show the code, that produces such a result.